# Solr field list (fl) function query can solve booleans?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to determine which side of a boolean was true and add it to the fl in solr?

For example, if I have a query with an fq:

```
&fq=(model:"Ford" OR colors:"Blue")
```

Can I add an fl to determine which side of the boolean was true? (assume colors is a multivalued/array field). Something like:

```
&fq=(model:"Ford" OR colors:"Blue")&fl=has_blue:colors:"Blue"
```

So in the response, if the model is ford, but it doesn't have a blue color I get has_blue: false

Answer (score 0):

Below Function query will solve your problem. Add that function query to your field list.

```
&fq=(model:"Ford" OR colors:"Blue")&fl=has_color:if(termfreq(colors,blue),true,false)
```